# How to deploy with password (MeteorJS)

Tags: deployment, meteor

Is it still possible to deploy to `meteor.com` and protect it using a password?

When I search for this I find things like

```
$> mrt deploy -P example.meteor.com
```

but that doesn't work. I guess something has changed here and I get the impression this feature is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor no longer supports deploying with a password directly, and for good reason!.

All publishes are linked to a Meteor developer account. These give:

1. Ability to allow other users to have access to your apps
2. Abililty to see all sites you have
3. Ability to publish without putting in your password every time
4. (In future) more fine grained permissions options (I'd imagine, considering galaxy's commercial target base).

Simply `meteor login`, or publish your app like you would normally to kick off the signup process. You can `meteor logout` to switch to another account.

Comment: thanks. However, when I login to `meteor.com` and go to my account, I don't have any `Developer Account Apps`, but I have a deployed application. How does that work ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri these apps are apps using your MDG account via OAuth (kind of like listing what apps have access to your facebook account in Meteor terms). As Cagdas mentions in the other answer, you can view the sites you have listed with `meteor list-sites`

Answer (score 1):

After you deploy your app, you can see the sites you are authorized with `meteor list-sites`.